# print out paging with css | page-break-before:always; cross-browser issue!

Tags: html, css, printing, cross-browser, page-break

I have an issue about print paging. you can see my code below. it is not making page break for the print preview :( any idea what can be the problem?

Appreciate helps!

---

HTML Code

```
<h1>header text</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum jhdfb jdhbg sdfgshdbfgkjhsdbgkjhbs d sdgf</p>    
<div class="pagebreak"></div>

<h1>header text</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum jhdfb jdhbg sdfgshdbfgkjhsdbgkjhbs d sdgf</p>    
<div class="pagebreak"></div>
```

---

CSS Code

```
@media screen {
    .pagebreak  { height:10px; background:url(img/page-break.gif) 0 center repeat-x; border-top:1px dotted #999; margin-bottom:13px; }
}
@media print {
    .pagebreak { height:0; page-break-before:always; margin:0; border-top:none; }
}
```

---

### SORTED!!

> I moved the pagebreak class to h1, also the html tag (h1) has to be not under
>   any other html tag :/ it was under <
>   div id="wrap"> and then I removed all
>   tags covering h1, and it works well
>   now! WEIRD!!

Comment: i actually create this output via php, dynamic content from db. but actually you are right, it is not an issue about php, sorry. i edit the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks perfect.  It works great for me using Firefox 3.5.5 and also in IE 8.0. I'll bet you're testing it in a browser that is not CSS2/3 compliant.  Change your browser and it'll work great.

This link lists support of CSS3 features: http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css

(The state of non-support in browsers is frustrating, isn't it?)

Comment: I thought about that issue actually. I have Mac [snow leopard] and running Safari on. I also tested on firefox, but it was same issue ! :( now I just download Opera and it works well under opera... i hope it doesnt mean it will not make paging when I print-out from safari :( ?

Comment: hmmm really bad!!! just tested to take printout from safari and it doesnt make paging :( is there any other way which wrks for all browser?

Comment: What if you take out the @media {} blocks?

Comment: @Pekka - no it doesnt help  :/

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link, I was looking through it and it does appear that `page-break-before: always` is supported by all browsers listed. Hmmm, are you sure your `<style>` tag doesn't have a media attribute? - that would cause it to ignore the `@media` blocks.